# How can I store mongo db collections to Google cloud storage directly?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-storage

I have created an instance in Google Compute Engine.Using SSH I am able to do operations with mongo db.Now I want the collections in mongo-db to be stored in Google Cloud Storage.How can I do that?I have searched for it but no help.

Comment: MongoDB storage engines need a file system location for all database storage. To use a service like google cloud storage you would need a way of "mounting" that service as a file system. See [gcfs](https://code.google.com/p/gcsfs/) for details. But an off-topic question for this programming site.

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud Storage is **not** suitable for applications requiring a filesystem, such as MongoDB -- the various "filesystem simulations" on top of GCS introduce just too much overhead to be deemed acceptable (at least by my personal standards).

Rather, to use MongoDB on GCE, use persistent disks on your GCE instances, either regular ones (cheaper) or SSD ones (costlier, faster).